# NodeJs Express how to handle items(params) that sent from frontend?

Tags: node.js, express, backend

Im new in backend development (using NodeJs Express).
Its very basic question (I didn't find any good tutorial about it)
Question is:

I have this line of code:

```
app.get('/test', function (req ,res){
  res.send('test');
});
```

What I wanna do is: BackEnd only sends `res` to FrontEnd, if FrontEnd send some JSON first.
Like Backend will show Something to FrontEnd, only if FrontEnd send JSON first;
How to handle it? What code to write?

Or what to type in google search to find this kind of tutorial

Comment: You are building a REST API with node. In REST we don't keep states. When we receive a request we process and respond. In the Front end, you can do wait until the response is received. use promises, async-await or callbacks to wait until the response in the Front end. To process the incoming JSON body use body-parser. Based on the request body you can process and send the response. PS: Every request should be given a response. That's how REST behaves.

Comment: Check out these client request libraries: [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch). With these you could send HTTP requests to the server with JavaScript.

Comment: If by "send some JSON first" you mean a previous request, then you need a session middleware to keep track of requests so when you are handling a request you'll know "oh, I REMEMBER this frontend guy, he sent a JSON earlier." Basically, after you set up a session management middleware like `express-session`,  you have `req.session` in each request handler, and it is shared across every request from a particular frontend. So you can set `req.seesion.hasSentJSON` to `true` for a frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You are building a REST API with node. In REST we don't keep states. When we receive a request we process and respond. In the Front end, you can do wait until the response is received. use promises, async-await or callbacks to wait until the response in the Front end. Use these methods to connect with back end from front-end [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). To process the incoming JSON body use body-parser. Based on the request body you can process and send the response. PS: Every request should be given a response. That's how REST behaves.

Answer (score 0):

**In Query**

yourbackend.com/test?message=welcomeToStackOverflow

This is how you can access with in  query:

```js
const {message} = req.query;
console.log(message);
// welcomeToStackOverflow
```

**In Params**

yourbackend.com/test/:message

This is how you can access with  in params :

```js
const {message} = req.params;
console.log(message);
// welcomeToStackOverflow
```

Here you have working example : https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-rosalind-37brf?file=/routes/test.js